# MYSQLI_QUERY not returning values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to figure out why my query is not working. I am trying to add all the amounts together for each month where `status = 'S'`. However, I get the following error. Any ideas?

```
[05-Jul-2013 11:21:30 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

My Code:

```
$closedsales = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MONTH(date) as month, sum(amount) as total FROM sales WHERE user_id = '".$userid."' AND status = 'S' GROUP BY MONTH(date)");

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($closedsales) ) {
    $closedsales[$row['month']] = $row['total'];
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$closedsales = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MONTH(date) as month, sum(amount) as total FROM sales WHERE user_id = '".$userid."' AND status = 'S' GROUP BY MONTH(date)");

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($closedsales) ) {
    $monthlysales[$row['month']] = $row['total'];
}


foreach($monthlysales as $monthlysale) {
echo $monthlysale;
echo "This worked...";
}
```

Thanks! I got rid of that error. However, for some reason my array does not contain anything. It only prints out `This worked...`

Is it possible this is because I don't have each month in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the assignment:

```
$closedsales[$row['month']] = $row['total'];
```

`$closedsales` is the result returned by `mysqli_query`, it's not an array you can assign to. Use a different variable for this.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch! I never knew that I couldn't reassign a new value to it. What a simple solution. Thanks buddy! I will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: If you reassign the variable, how do you expect the next iteration of `mysqli_fetch_row($closedsales)` to work?

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect since now. Thanks for explaining that! I feel dumb now. I am noticing that my array is blank. Could that be b/c I dont have each month in the DB? See above

Comment: That should make the array empty, those months simply won't be in the array.

Comment: Ok thanks! Just got to debug this since the `foreach` is only looping once. Thanks again for the main fix!

Comment: If it's only looping once, it means there was only one row in the query result. Try running the query by hand with phpmyadmin or mysql.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32966/discussion-between-chris78-and-barmar)

Comment: Figured it out :) `$monthlysales[$row['0']] = $row['1'];`

Comment: You should call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to make the original code work.